# highcharts not showing the line graph

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, jsx, react-highcharts

I am working on an assignment where I am using highcharts in ReactJS application. When I hardcode the values of 'data' as below, the line graph shows

```
data : [10,20,30,40]
```

However if I create the data through code using `prices.push(value)` and then assign `data : [this.prices]` it does not work.

Please note while debugging i see all the values are there in prices. What could be the problem?

```
render() {
        const options = {
            title: {
              text: 'Historical Prices Chart',
            },
            xAxis: {
              categories: ['February 1st 2018','January 31st 2018','January 30th 2018','January 29th 2018'],
            },
            yAxis: {
              title: {
                text: 'Prices',
              },
            },
            chart: {
              type: 'line',
            },
            series: [
              {
                name: 'Pulses',
                data: this.prices,
              }
            ],
          };
```

`console.log(this.prices)` gives me -

```
[10,20,30,40]
```

Complete code is (Its a React Component that gets historical prices of cryptos) -

```
class History extends Component {

constructor () {
    super();
    this.state = {
        todayprice: {},
        yesterdayprice: {},
        twodaysprice: {},
        threedaysprice: {},
        fourdaysprice: {}
    };
    this.getBTCPrices = this.getBTCPrices.bind(this);
    this.getETHPrices = this.getETHPrices.bind(this);
    this.getLTCPrices = this.getLTCPrices.bind(this);

    this.xAxisdates=[];
    this.btcPastPrices=[];
    this.ethPastPrices=[];
    this.ltcPastPrices=[];
}    

// This function gets the ETH price for a specific timestamp/date. The date is passed in as an argument
getETHPrices (date) {
    return axios.get('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricehistorical?fsym=ETH&tsyms=INR&ts=' + date);
}
// This function gets the BTC price for a specific timestamp/date. The date is passed in as an argument
getBTCPrices (date) {
    return axios.get('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricehistorical?fsym=BTC&tsyms=INR&ts=' + date);
}
// This function gets the LTC price for a specific timestamp/date. The date is passed in as an argument
getLTCPrices (date) {
    return axios.get('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricehistorical?fsym=LTC&tsyms=INR&ts=' + date);
}

// This function gets the prices for the current date.
getTodayPrice () {
    // Get today's date in timestamp
    let t = moment().unix()
    // axios.all is used to make concurrent API requests. These requests were the functions we first created and they accept an argument of the date required.
    axios.all([this.getETHPrices(t), this.getBTCPrices(t), this.getLTCPrices(t)])
        .then(axios.spread((eth, btc, ltc) => {
            let f = {
                date: moment.unix(t).format("MMMM Do YYYY"),
                eth: eth.data.ETH.INR,
                btc: btc.data.BTC.INR,
                ltc: ltc.data.LTC.INR
            }
            // Set the state of todayprice to the content of the object f
            this.setState({ todayprice: f });
            this.xAxisdates.push(f.date);
            this.btcPastPrices.push(f.btc);
            this.ethPastPrices.push(f.eth);
            this.ltcPastPrices.push(f.ltc);
        }));
}
// This function gets the prices for the yesterday.
getYesterdayPrice () {
    // Get yesterday's date in timestamp
    let t = moment().subtract(1, 'days').unix();
    // axios.all is used to make concurrent API requests. These requests were the functions we first created and they accept an argument of the date required.
    axios.all([this.getETHPrices(t), this.getBTCPrices(t), this.getLTCPrices(t)])
        .then(axios.spread((eth, btc, ltc) => {
            let f = {
                date: moment.unix(t).format("MMMM Do YYYY"),
                eth: eth.data.ETH.INR,
                btc: btc.data.BTC.INR,
                ltc: ltc.data.LTC.INR
            }
            // Set the state of yesterdayprice to the content of the object f
            this.setState({ yesterdayprice: f });

            this.xAxisdates.push(f.date);
            this.btcPastPrices.push(f.btc);
            this.ethPastPrices.push(f.eth);
            this.ltcPastPrices.push(f.ltc);
        }));
}
// This function gets the prices for the two days ago.
getTwoDaysPrice () {
    // Get the date for two days ago in timestamp
    let t = moment().subtract(2, 'days').unix();
    // axios.all is used to make concurrent API requests. These requests were the functions we first created and they accept an argument of the date required.
    axios.all([this.getETHPrices(t), this.getBTCPrices(t), this.getLTCPrices(t)])
        .then(axios.spread((eth, btc, ltc) => {
            let f = {
                date: moment.unix(t).format("MMMM Do YYYY"),
                eth: eth.data.ETH.INR,
                btc: btc.data.BTC.INR,
                ltc: ltc.data.LTC.INR
            }
            // Set the state of twodaysprice to the content of the object f
            this.setState({ twodaysprice: f });
            this.xAxisdates.push(f.date);
            this.btcPastPrices.push(f.btc);
            this.ethPastPrices.push(f.eth);
            this.ltcPastPrices.push(f.ltc);
        }));
}
// This function gets the prices for the three days ago.
getThreeDaysPrice () {
    // Get the date for three days ago in timestamp
    let t = moment().subtract(3, 'days').unix();
    // axios.all is used to make concurrent API requests. These requests were the functions we first created and they accept an argument of the date required.
    axios.all([this.getETHPrices(t), this.getBTCPrices(t), this.getLTCPrices(t)])
        .then(axios.spread((eth, btc, ltc) => {
            let f = {
                date: moment.unix(t).format("MMMM Do YYYY"),
                eth: eth.data.ETH.INR,
                btc: btc.data.BTC.INR,
                ltc: ltc.data.LTC.INR
            }
            // Set the state of threedaysprice to the content of the object f
            this.setState({ threedaysprice: f });
            this.xAxisdates.push(f.date);
            this.btcPastPrices.push(f.btc);
            this.ethPastPrices.push(f.eth);
            this.ltcPastPrices.push(f.ltc);
        }));
}
// This function gets the prices for the four days ago.
getFourDaysPrice () {
    // Get the date for four days ago in timestamp
    let t = moment().subtract(4, 'days').unix();
    // axios.all is used to make concurrent API requests. These requests were the functions we first created and they accept an argument of the date required.
    axios.all([this.getETHPrices(t), this.getBTCPrices(t), this.getLTCPrices(t)])
        .then(axios.spread((eth, btc, ltc) => {
            let f = {
                date: moment.unix(t).format("MMMM Do YYYY"),
                eth: eth.data.ETH.INR,
                btc: btc.data.BTC.INR,
                ltc: ltc.data.LTC.INR
            }
            // Set the state of fourdaysprice to the content of the object f
            this.setState({ fourdaysprice: f });
            this.xAxisdates.push(f.date);
            this.btcPastPrices.push(f.btc);
            this.ethPastPrices.push(f.eth);
            this.ltcPastPrices.push(f.ltc);
        }));
}
// This is called when an instance of a component is being created and inserted into the DOM.
componentWillMount () {     
    this.getTodayPrice();
    this.getYesterdayPrice();
    this.getTwoDaysPrice();
    this.getThreeDaysPrice();
    this.getFourDaysPrice();
}

render() {    
    const options = {
        title: {
          text: 'Historical Prices Chart',
        },
        xAxis: {
          categories: ['February 1st 2018','January 31st 2018','January 30th 2018','January 29th 2018'],
        },
        yAxis: {
          title: {
            text: 'Prices',
          },
        },
        chart: {
          type: 'line',
        },
        series: [
          {
            name: 'BTC',
            data: this.btcPastPrices,
          },
          {
            name: 'ETH',
            data: [20,10,30,40],
          },
          {
            name: 'LTC',
            data: [5,28,10,20],
          },
        ],
      };

    return (
        // JSX Code
        <div className="history--section container">
                <h2>History (Past 5 days)</h2>
                <div className="history--section__box">
                    <div className="history--section__box__inner">
                        <h4>{this.state.todayprice.date}</h4>
                        <div className="columns">
                            <div className="column">
                                <p>1 BTC = INR{this.state.todayprice.btc}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="column">
                                <p>1 ETH = INR{this.state.todayprice.eth}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="column">
                                <p>1 LTC = INR{this.state.todayprice.ltc}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="history--section__box__inner">
                        <h4>{this.state.yesterdayprice.date}</h4>
                        <div className="columns">
                            <div className="column">
                                <p>1 BTC = INR{this.state.yesterdayprice.btc}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="column">
                                <p>1 ETH = INR{this.state.yesterdayprice.eth}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="column">
                                <p>1 LTC = INR{this.state.yesterdayprice.ltc}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="history--section__box__inner">
                        <h4>{this.state.twodaysprice.date}</h4>
                        <div className="columns">
                            <div className="column">
                                <p>1 BTC = INR{this.state.twodaysprice.btc}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="column">
                                <p>1 ETH = INR{this.state.twodaysprice.eth}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="column">
                                <p>1 LTC = INR{this.state.twodaysprice.ltc}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="history--section__box__inner">
                        <h4>{this.state.threedaysprice.date}</h4>
                        <div className="columns">
                            <div className="column">
                                <p>1 BTC = INR{this.state.threedaysprice.btc}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="column">
                                <p>1 ETH = INR{this.state.threedaysprice.eth}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="column">
                                <p>1 LTC = INR{this.state.threedaysprice.ltc}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="history--section__box__inner">
                        <h4>{this.state.fourdaysprice.date}</h4>
                        <div className="columns">
                            <div className="column">
                                <p>1 BTC = INR{this.state.fourdaysprice.btc}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="column">
                                <p>1 ETH = INR{this.state.fourdaysprice.eth}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="column">
                                <p>1 LTC = INR{this.state.fourdaysprice.ltc}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <p>{this.xAxisdates}</p>
                <p>{this.btcPastPrices}</p>
                <p>{this.ethPastPrices}</p>
                <p>{this.ltcPastPrices}</p>
                <Chart options={options} />
            </div>
    );
}
}
export default History;
```

Comment: @ewolden, I have added the complete file in the query

Comment: When you place [10,20,30,40] in data : [this.prices], it means that you have data : [[10,20,30,40]] which is wrong. Are you able to simplify the demo as live in jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @SebastianBochan You can see in the full code and the highcharts code that he does not use double brackets. I think he wrote it that way for clarification. Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/knu7w2mo/

Comment: I have added [] for understanding

Comment: Thanks, anyway will be really good to have a live demo of unworking demo. It will allow me to debug it, because in simple way (mentioned jsfiddle) works well (including add references to external data). 
@Ashish K Agarwal Could you simplyfy your code and create live demo of chart?